# JTable does not refresh, when i add data to the database (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtable

```
insert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    try{

                        String sql1 = "Insert into supplier (SupplierID, CompanyName,PhoneNumber) values (?,?,?)";
                        Connection conn = null;
                       conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Jela\\Desktop\\repo\\Master\\Working\\database.db");
                       PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
                       pst.setString(1, supplierID.getText());
                       pst.setString(2, companyname.getText());
                       pst.setString(3, contactnumber.getText());

                       pst.execute();

                       System.out.println("data inserted");
                       conn.close();

                    }catch(Exception e2){

                    System.out.println(e2);
                    }

   try{
    String sql2 = "Select * FROM supplier";
    Connection conn1 = null;
    conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Jela\\Desktop\\repo\\Master\\Working\\database.db");
    PreparedStatement pst = conn1.prepareStatement(sql2);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
  table.setModel(model1);
  conn1.close();

        }catch(Exception e3){
        System.out.println(e3);
        }

            }

        });
```

i have an insert button, and when i click the insert button data should be added to the database. However the data only appears when i close my program and start again. I started the update code, but it does not update. Could anyone give me some hints of how i can update the database in a JTable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the select statement with sql2 work?

Comment: Does it give you an exception?

Comment: You never close your connection by the way..

Comment: well i dont really know, as  that part is my code for updating the jtable

Comment: it does not give me an exception

Comment: I appreciate your editing down your code for brevity, but it's not clear where `model` comes from.  Are you adding the results of the query to an existing TableModel, or is `model` a brand new TableModel?

Comment: im adding the resultsto an existing datatablemodel called model

Comment: I guess this is wrong table.setModel(model); Are you sure that the update does not work? Isn't it more likely that the processing of the ResultSet  does not work?

Comment: my update does not work. i can insert data and it will be sotred in the databse, but i cant view it straight away, only if i exit the program and start

Answer (score 0):

Add a `finally` block after the `catch` which closes your connection and preparedStatement.

```
 ...
 } finally {

        if (pst!= null) {
            pst.close();
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            conn .close();
}
```

Another way to close your resources is to use the try-with-resources statement

```
 try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionURL);
       PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, would the update function work if i close the connection

Comment: it helped me, however the update function still does not work

Comment: i closed both conn and conn1 connection, but with no success